# Button clicked display in the list of buttons using CSS only

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have 4 buttons in an HTML which is in list (ul > li) format. I want to implement a functionality where one of the buttons will be shown as clicked (clicked css style applied). Then on clicking any other button in the list, the already clicked button style should change and then only the newly clicked button should be shown as clicked (clicked css style applied). Thereby, other buttons will have unclicked style.

This can be handled using javascipt, but I'm specifically looking to achieve this with only css. I'm unable to solve this.

I'm new to CSS programming and hence requesting help in this regard.

Comment: can you please provide your code?

Comment: if you don't care about a click elsewhere outside your buttons then `:focus`pseudoclass can help you.

Comment: This is my HTML DOM structure. I'm looking of clicking event itself.

<ul>                   
                    <li>
                       <input type="button" value="A"/>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="button" value="B"/>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="button" value="C"/>
                    </li>
                     <li>
                      <input type="button" value="D"/>
                    </li>
                    
                </ul>

Comment: apply a class when clicked, say `active`. Remove that class from all the other buttons. use jquery addClass removeClass Methods.

Comment: This is not possible using CSS only. There is no pseudo class, which stays active after being clicked and focussed away. You are required to use JavaScript. Simply add a class to the button (e.g. ``active``) and style it the way you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class to the clicked element after removing that class from all other elements. Use jquery `addClass` and `removeClass` methods.The only extend you can achieve using css with input tags is by using the pseudo class `:focus`(any click outside the button will remove the focus though.). Its not possible to keep the styles if you are going to click on anywhere outside the button.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type=button]').click(function(){
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.active{
  background:white;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul> <li> <input type="button" value="A"/> </li> <li> <input type="button" value="B"/> </li> <li> <input type="button" value="C"/> </li> <li> <input type="button" value="D"/> </li> </ul>
```

If you want to avoid jquery then use selector.className (type string) or selector.classList (type array).

**EDIT**

If you are willing to use anchor instead of input tag then I've a pure css solution for you.

```css
a {
    display: block;
    border: 2px solid black;
    text-align: center;
  margin:5px;
  text-decoration:none;
}



a:active,a:target {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  <ul> <li> <a href="#a" id="a"/>a</a> </li> <li> <a href="#b" id="b"/>b</a> </li> <li> <a href="#c" id="c"/>c</a> </li> <li>  <a href="#d" id="d"/>d</a> </li> </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: He does not want to use JavaScript, so this doesn't really answer his question. You need to specify, that it is not possible with CSS. (``:focus`` is not really an alternative)

Comment: I've explained that it is not possible to keep the styles if the user clicks on the outside of the button. @ssc-hrep3

Comment: Thanks to all for your suggestions. I'm now sure that we cannot get it working with only CSS.

Comment: @user3220129 Check the edited answer. I've got a solution with only css